# Build Emgu from sources. Failed to run MSBuild command error (Windows 10, VS2017)

Tags: build, cmake, msbuild, emgucv

I'm trying to build Emgu from sources on Windows 10 using CMake 3.10.2 and following the instructions [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Building_from_Git).

After running the script `Build_Binary_x86-64_doc.bat` I'm getting the following error (even building from VS2017 developer console):

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.16299.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    The system cannot find the file specified



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/_repositories/emgucv/b/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your trying to build from Visual Studio 2017 developer command prompt? If not doing so, please try. Lots of environment variables are set when a devloper command prompt is started.

Comment: Thanks @vre I tried also but same output!

Comment: Did you clean the `CMakeCache.txt` before running from developer command prompt? If yes, what happens if you type `MSBuild /?` in the developer command prompt?

Comment: Hi @vre thanks for your help. Seems I got to fix it. After some tries I've reinstall the "VC++ compiler and libraries" using the VSInstaller and the script seems to work now from the Developer console :)